# Executors Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Возможно ли использовать один gitlab-runner с несколькими executor.
Например shell и docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Оказывается gitlab-runner можно зарегистрировать несколько раз с разными executor, и использовать.